# Speed up selecting positive eigenvalues repeatedly

Tags: performance-tuning, eigenvalues

I have a smallish (e.g. 2x2 or 4x4, but ideally up to 10x10) non-symmetric square matrix $\mathbf{A}(x)$. I need to define a function $f(x)$ which is the sum of the eigenvalues with positive real part of $\mathbf{A}(x)$, for $x \in [x_a,x_b]$.

I then wish to use this function as a normalisation factor within a system of differential equations, $\mathbf{y}= (\mathbf{Q}(x) - f(x) \cdot \mathbf{I}) \,\mathbf{y}$.

For a small initial example, for the 2x2 case $\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{A}$.

```
A = {{0, 1}, {-1 + x^2, 0}};
Q = A;
```

The eigenvalues here become imaginary for $|x|<1$, so I need to be able to detect those transitions cleanly.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Eigenvalues[A], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

```
xa = -4; xb = 4;
yVector = {y[1][x], y[2][x]};
ICs = {y[1][xa] == 0, y[2][xa] == 1};

Clear[eee, totalPosEigs];
eee[z_] = Eigenvalues[N[A/.x->z]];
totalPosEigs[z_?NumericQ] := 
  totalPosEigs[z] = (Sow[z]; Total@Select[eee[z], Re[#] > 0 &]);
yeqn = Thread[D[yVector, x] == (Q - totalPosEigs[x]*IdentityMatrix[Length[Q]]).yVector];
NDSolve[{yeqn, ICs}, 
  Array[y, {Length[yVector]}], {x, xa, xb}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 (* {0.01045, Null} *)
```

This works, and is fast enough for the 2x2 case. However, as the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ gets larger (here 4x4), this approach gets a bit too clunky (and Q is now 6x6):

```
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, 
   {-(1/ϵ^4), -((4 Cos[x])/ϵ^2), -((4 Sin[x])/ϵ^2), 0}} /. ϵ -> 1/10;
Q = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {-220 Cos[x], -220 Sin[x], 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {10000, 0, 0, -220 Sin[x], 0, 1}, {0, 10000, 0, 220 Cos[x], 0, 0}};
```

The eigenvalue structure is also more complicated in this case:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Re@Eigenvalues[A], {x, xa, xb}]
```

[image]

```
xa = -4; xb = 4;
yVector = Through[Array[y, {Length[Q]}][x]];
ICs = {y[1][xa] == 0, y[2][xa] == 0, y[3][xa] == 0, y[4][xa] == 0, 
   y[5][xa] == -1, y[6][xa] == 0};
Clear[eee, totalPosEigs];
eee[z_] = Eigenvalues[N[A /. x -> z]];
totalPosEigs[z_?NumericQ] := 
  totalPosEigs[z] = (Sow[z]; Chop@Total@Select[eee[z], Re[#] > 0 &]);
yeqn = Thread[D[yVector, x] == (Q - totalPosEigs[x]*IdentityMatrix[Length[Q]]).yVector];
AbsoluteTiming[{sol, {pts}} = 
   Reap[NDSolve[{yeqn, ICs}, Array[y, {Length[yVector]}], {x, xa, xb}]];]
{0.229799, Null}
```

Here `totalPosEigs` has been evaluated 567 times (even with caching), each evaluation is fast but they are adding up to contribute most of the time of the calculation. If I was to just use the sum of the absolute value of the eigenvalues for instance it takes a quarter of the time, so the `Select` is a large part of the slowdown.

Its worth noting that the change points may have an imaginary part when they become positive, and the matrix may contain interpolation functions of $x$.

Comment: To clarify: do you need the sum of the positive eigenvalues (as your text says: positive real part and zero imaginary part) or the sum of the eigenvalues with positive real part (as your code says: positive real part and arbitrary imaginary part)?

Comment: @Roman, sorry, positive real part yes. I'll clarify that, thanks.

Comment: There is no need to `Sow`/`Reap` the points at which `totalPosEigs` is called, as these are stored as `DownValues` anyway. You can extract them with `pts = Cases[DownValues[totalPosEigs], RuleDelayed[_[totalPosEigs[x_]], y_] /; NumericQ[x] && NumericQ[y] :> {x, y}]` after the code finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm. I would have set up this system as follows and this way, it is about 5 times as fast:

```
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-(1/ϵ^4), -((4 Cos[x])/ϵ^2), -((4 Sin[x])/ϵ^2), 0}} /. ϵ -> 1/10;
Q = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {-220 Cos[x], -220 Sin[x], 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {10000, 0, 0, -220 Sin[x], 0, 1}, {0, 10000, 0, 220 Cos[x], 0, 0}};

n = Length[Q];
cA = With[{code = N@A}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
cQ = With[{code = N@Q}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]];

sysmat[x_?NumericQ] := With[{
    λ = (1. - UnitStep[-Re[#]]).# &@Eigenvalues[cA[x]]
    },
   cQ[x] - DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[λ, n]]
   ];

xa = -4; xb = 4;    
Y0 = {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0};
Ysol = NDSolveValue[{
      Y'[x] == sysmat[x].Y[x],
      Y[xa] == Y0
      },
     Y, {x, xa, xb}
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.043133

Most essential steps:

- Compiling definitions of `A` and `Q`.
- Teplacing `Select` by `UnitStep` and `Total` by `Dot`.
- Performing all relevant computation in `sysmat` with scoped variables so that memoization is actually not required.

## Addendum

OP asked whether this would work also with `ParametricNDSolveValue` if `A` and `Q` depend on a further parameter, say `z`. My first idea was to add `z` as a further argument `sysmat` to `sysmat`, but upon calling `ParametricNDSolveValue`, this resulted in an error message

> "Dependent variables {Y,sysmat[x,z]} cannot depend on parameters {z}."

I hve no idea for what reason this happens. I consider it a bug.

One can circumvent this by submitting also `Y[x]` as variable to the function `F` on the right hand side of the ODE:

```
F[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, Y_?VectorQ] := 
  With[{λ = (1. - UnitStep[-Re[#]]).# &@Eigenvalues[cA[x]]},
   (cQ[x] - DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[λ, n]]).Y
   ];

Y0 = {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0};
Ysol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
     {
      Y'[x] == F[x, z, Y[x]],
      Y[xa] == Y0
      },
     Y,
     {x, xa, xb},
     z
     ];
```

*(I am well aware that the parameter `z` does not effect the result.)*

Comment: Thank you Henrik. I don't think the compilation is making any real difference here, but the `UnitStep`/`Dot` magic instead of `Select` makes such a difference.

Comment: Actually, compiling the functions `cA` and `cQ` here takes ~0.1 seconds each, the compilation is helping the speed (when there are no interpolation functions in the matrix, else compiling needs `MainEvaluate` anyway) but at the trade-off of the time to compile it. I can probably rewrite my code to only need to compile once for multiple parameters.

Comment: Yes, of course: You may add just further arguments to the compiled functions to supply further parameters.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, i rewrote my code to only compile once for all x and another parameter and to use the vectorized form.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to use `ParametricNDSolve` for this system, in the case where $A$ and $Q$ both depend on another parameter (say $z$)?

Comment: I believe I've understood what you mean. Please see my recent edit and check whether this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you again. I did the first step and got the same error about dependent variables,  hence i was asking.